# Was it actually possible to 'store' things in the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: harry-potter

I have come across a few questions on this site where people ask "how did x store/take out y from the Mirror?", so were the things actually stored in the Mirror?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, all evidence points to the fact that Dumbledore stored the Philosopher's Stone *inside* the Mirror of Erised.

We know that the original purpose of the Mirror was to show the viewer their "heart's desire". However, according to JKR, Dumbledore specifically *changed* the enchantment on the Mirror to "hide" the Stone in it:

> Only after Professor Dumbledore ***makes key modifications*** to the mirror (which has been languishing in the Room of Requirement for a century or so before he brings it out and puts it to work) does it become a superb hiding place, and the final test for the impure of heart. <sup>[src](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-mirror-of-erised)</sup>

The term modifications implies that hiding the Stone was not done by using the Mirror's original purpose at all; it was something else, a different behavior that that Mirror was updated to perform. And given that Dumbledore specifically changed the mirror to be a hiding place, the most reasonable explanation is that he turned it *into* that hiding place directly.

Comment: This is cheating. People like me who only use the book are always outsmarted. *Why* does JKR have to answer fans' questions?

Comment: Because she's got a genetic inability to *stop writing about Harry Potter*? :)

Comment: There is no indication anywhere in the books that Dumbledore modified the Mirror. If JKR suddenly says that he did, what are we to believe?

Comment: @cst1992: There is indication, I think. The quote from *Philosopher's Stone* at the start of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63337/4918 hints that Professor Dumbledore might have done a modification on the mirror.  If the mirror had already been a secure hiding place without Professor Dumbledore doing anything, then using it to store the Stone wouldn't count as such a brilliant idea.

Comment: @cst1992 To the best of my knowledge, JKR's Pottermore writings are considered canon by the Harry Potter fandom, second only to the books themselves; if she says something on Pottermore and it doesn't contradict the books, it's "truth" as far as HP is concerned...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield The suggestion that Dumbledore knew about the Room of Requirement does potentially contradict the books, though, since he at least pretends to be completely unaware of it.

Comment: that is true. but I feel like Dumbledore pretends to not know a lot of things he actually knows

Comment: @cst1992 Why does JKR have to answer fans' questions?  Because *that's what good writers do.*  It makes sense from many different perspectives:  1) It keeps them happy; without fans, who will buy their books and keep putting food on their tables?  2) it's a way to engage socially with people with a common interest.  3) it rewards the most devoted fans--the ones who actually attend events where they can meet the author--with special perks.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: That is true in general, and was all well in the case of JKR before c. 2005, when she had interviews in the fans and actually answered relevant questions about the story, plot points, and character motivations.  But these days, she's trying to do random worldbuilding writeups about the greater wizarding world, irrelevant to the books, and she's *very bad* at it.  She should never have written the two companion books and most of what's on Pottermore and new Pottermore.  Selling out by giving her name to useless junk she invents doesn't keep fans happy.

Answer (score 3):

As a tentative answer, I don't think that's the case.
As a similar example, take the Sorting Hat.

When a true Gryffindor showed need of the Sword of Gryffindor, they could pull it out from the hat. That means it was just wired that way, that the said person *received* the Sword, through the Hat. Similar was the Room of Requirement, which provided something that a person wished. We know, in the Sword's case, that it was stored in Dumbledore's office, behind his desk in the glass case.

The Mirror was just a magical medium of showing one's true desire, the person just needed to 'tweak the desire', to trigger the outcome.

Comment: So where was the stone, if not "in" the mirror?

Comment: Anywhere, where only Dumbledore, or probably also Flamel, knew it was. It was transported due to the Mirror, in Harry's pocket.

Comment: So what is the point of all the defenses if it's so well hidden that only Dumbledore/Flamel knows where it is?

Comment: The enchantments were placed there before the Mirror. It's possible that the Stone was actually lying in the last Chamber before Quirrell tried to get to it. Then it was moved and the Mirror placed there instead of it. Also, didn't you read Book 7? Just because Dumbledore thinks it's well hidden doesn't mean no one will find it. Harry does end up finding it in spite of all the enchantments.

Comment: this is making even less sense now. if you're removing the stone, why would you put IN the one thing that could possibly be used to retrieve the stone from its new super-secret hiding place?

Comment: Not in, but past. The only one who wanted to find the Stone, not use it, will be able to get it. This makes the Stone Voldemort-proof, as he definitely wants to use it, and that'll be his top desire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34545/discussion-between-cst1992-and-phantom42).

Comment: @phantom42 In a different dimension? Maybe, stored in the enchantment itself. Why would you think it needs to be physically stored somewhere in a magical universe?

Comment: I don't see how this line of thinking makes sense. If the stone is already secure some place, why provide a *second* avenue for retrieving it from wherever it is already securely held?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say he *stored* the Stone in the Mirror of Erised. As we know, the Mirror shows each person their deepest and most desperate desire of the heart. While I agree with @MikeEdenfield in that Dumbledore used the enchantments of the Mirror and tweaked them slightly to protect the Stone, I wouldn't say the Mirror was *storing* the Stone. As Dumbledore tells Harry in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 17: The Man With Two Faces*

> You see, only one who wanted to 
>   find the Stone – find it, but not 
>   use it – would be able to get it, otherwise they’d just see themselves making gold or drinking Elixir of Life.

I think Dumbledore enchanted the room as well, in connection to the mirror. If the Mirror recognized somebody's desire to "find the Stone, but not use it" it would trigger the charm in the room. The Stone was hidden in the room by a controlled Vanishing charm, causing the Stone to reappear when triggered by the Mirror. Dumbledore definitely used the Mirror to hide the Stone, but not to *store* it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on how you define "inside". Is a pocket-ish dimension that can only be accessed through a specific magical object automatically the "interior" of that object? The discussions so far make me conclude that this is what the question amounts to. Because the way I read it, **the Mirror is absolutely mandatory for accessing wherever the Stone actually is,** otherwise the Mirror would have no point.